# Сравнить 2 стринговых массива

Tags: c#, массивы

Нигде не могу найти хорошего описания того, как сравнить 2 массива. Я представляю примерно такой код, как ниже, но результат все время получается не тот, что требуется (еще и кучу др. вариантов перепробовал).

Т.е. в результате в **List<string>keywords** должны быть записаны элементы, которые содержатся в обоих массивах.

```
                for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++)
            {
                for (int j = 0; j < array2.Length; j++)
                {
                    if (array1[i] == array2[j]) 
                    { 
                    keywords.Add(array2[j]);
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: @pontekorvo, судя по всему, вас не интересуют повторения, а значит вы должны искать первое совпадение и заканчивать на этом обработку элемента. Другими словами, вам нужен Contains (если это совсем низкоуровневый массив, то его можно написать, там ничего сложного, итерируем массив, нашли элемент - вернули true), а вместо List - Set (не знаю точного названия в с#, но он наверняка там есть):


    for (int i = 0; i < array1.Length; i++) {
         if (array2.Contains(array1[i])) {
             set.Add(array1[i]);
         }
    }

Comment: Надо не пробовать кучу вариантов, а думать. И читать умные книги. Вот такую, например - http://www.ozon.ru/context/detail/id/2468511/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
List<string> keywords = array1.Where(t => array2.Contains(t)).ToList<string>();
```

Answer (score 3):

```
using System;
using System.Linq;

namespace Intersect
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            string[] array1 = { "John", "Mary", "Xavier" };
            string[] array2 = { "Mary", "Nick", "John" };
            foreach (string i in array1.Intersect(array2))
            {
                Console.WriteLine(i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

У String есть метод Equal, попробуй использовать его в проверке на равенство.
Можешь также воспользоваться LINQ

```
var ar = array1.Where(x => array2.Any(y => y.Equals(x)).ToArray();
```

Так ты сразу получишь массив-результат, содержащий общие, между array1 и array2, элементы

Comment: не работает твой код - ругается на параметр (y)